# Raphael - find bounding box of text BEFORE printing

Tags: text, raphael, bounding-box

Afternoon All,

I'm trying to draw a dynamic "ruler" which can be zoomed (along with the rest of the page) and is annotated, using Raphael.

I've found Raphael's pathBBox() and isBBoxIntersect very useful for determining if a graduation should be printed at a certain point or if it would be too close to another and should thus be skipped.

Now I need to annotate some of the graduations and want to follow a similar method - annotate the largest graduations, working down to the smallest level of detail but skipping drawing the text if it would intersect with some already drawn.

Unfortunately my look through the Raphael docs have only shown me the Paper.print() and Paper.text() methods, both of which add to the paper.  This means I would have to add, then find the bbox and test, then remove if bad - which is potentially rather slow.

Is there a way to find the dimensions of some text I want to print without printing it, such that I can manually create a bbox object and test it against my stored bboxes?

As always, thanks very much in advance! :-)

Cheers,
-Oli

Answer (score 0):

You can use .getBBox() on text:

```
 var text = paper.text(...);
 if (text.getBBox().width > max) ...;
```

I didn't see this documented officially, but it works, and apparently cross-browser.

Comment: Yeah...found that and am playing with it at the mo... trouble is, paper.text prints it on the paper, whereas I want to get the planned text's bounding box before deciding whether to print it

Comment: Agh... I'm afraid it just plain doesn't have one until you put it on the canvas. However, you can set opacity=0 until you decide whether or not to display it.

Comment: Hmm, that is a VERY interesting idea, Peter, it might just do the job.  Good thinking :-)

Comment: if you're going down that route, you better call `hide()` and `show()`, accordingly, on the `shape`.

Comment: @Eliran Malka why?  Are you sure .getBBox() works on hidden elements?  I'm not sure but can't test now. I do know that it works on zero opacity elements (as do events, which can be handy sometimes).